# Can't connect to MongoDB through PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, pecl, nosql

I just wanted to take a look at Mongo-DB. But i just don't get it running. I've installed it with PECL and my `phpinfo()` tells me that the extension is loaded, but when i try to get a connection with

`$mongo = new Mongo();`

I get this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with
>   message ': Transport endpoint is not connected'

Anybody have the same Problem? ... Or any Idea on this?

Comment: Which OS do you use? Can you connect to the server using the mongo command line client (on the same machine)?

Comment: I also cannot connect to mongodb but the error is this: Class 'Mongo' not found. Do you have an idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please don't take this the wrong way, but have you actually got the server running? Only it looks like your error relates to a failure to connect and you've made no mention of the server or where it is located (localhost on the default port for example)

Comment: Shame on me!!! :-) Exactly this was my Problem. Anyhow I thought the PHP-Extension would start the Daemon automatically, and I didn't even thought about that.

Thanks for your Post!

Answer (score 8):

any server start method, such as "/etc/init.d/mongodb start" or "service start mongodb" will fail, if a stale lock file still exists. In Ubuntu/Debian this is /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock. Look for this and delte it, if it exists and seems to be an old one.

Answer (score 2):

check out whether server is running or not..

/etc/init.d/mongodb start

then go to

root@kannan-desktop:~# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.6.3
connecting to: test
>

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to change the IP in your `mongod.conf` if it's a new installation.

Answer (score 1):

custom string looks like that

```
mongodb://username:password@host:port/database
```

Answer (score 0):

First Change the Default db path by following command

**$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db/**

**$ sudo chown `id -u` /data/db**

and then the final command is..

**$ mongod --journal**

Do not close terminal until you are working with mongoDB

It works for me...

Answer (score 0):

just write `mongod` in your terminal and will work well