# Transport endpoint is not connected in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database

I am using

> rockmongo (Mongodb database).

I have a issue: `"sometimes i got error 'Transport endpoint is not connected' display and disconnect database with web-application."`

Then i `remove lock` file and `restart server` then start again but within 1 min again repeat same issue.

I don't understand issue with rockmongo. Have any one solution?

Comment: Checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173155/cant-connect-to-mongodb-through-php
Hope it helps.

Comment: I not got fatal error. My error: EMongoDB failed to open connection: Transport endpoint is not connected.

Comment: How is your server setup? Is it on a VM? Is the rockmongo files on a ns partition?

Comment: Rockmongo on linux server and server is our local pc. ns partition is not getting.